# Reporting Services Integration with Java and NetBeans

Tags: java, soap, reporting-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I have the following problem. I try to consume soap services in java from SSRS, for this, I use the web services assistant that comes with netbeans (jax-ws (web services client)). Once I have the classes generated in my project, I try to render a report.

```
    ReportExecutionService service = new ReportExecutionService();
    ReportExecutionServiceSoap rs = service.getReportExecutionServiceSoap();

    String reportPath = "/PruebaJuan";
    String format = "HTML4.0";
    String devInfo = "<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";
    Holder<byte[]> result = new Holder<byte[]>();
    Holder<String> extension = new Holder<String>();
    Holder<String> mimeType = new Holder<String>();
    Holder<String> encoding = new Holder<String>();
    Holder<ArrayOfWarning> warnings = new Holder<ArrayOfWarning>();
    Holder<ArrayOfString> streamIDs = new Holder<ArrayOfString>();
    try {
        ExecutionInfo execInfo = rs.loadReport(reportPath, null);
        rs.render(format, devInfo, result, extension, mimeType, encoding, warnings, streamIDs);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println(result.value);
```

And this is the error that I'm getting:

```
    javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The session identifier is missing. A session identifier is required for this operation. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.MissingSessionIdException: The session identifier is missing. A session identifier is required for this operation.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportExecution2005Impl.InternalRender(String Format, String DeviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, Stream& Result, String& Extension, String& MimeType, String& Encoding, Warning[]& Warnings, String[]& StreamIds)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportExecution2005Impl.Render(String Format, String DeviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, Byte[]& Result, String& Extension, String& MimeType, String& Encoding, Warning[]& Warnings, String[]& StreamIds)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportExecutionService.Render(String Format, String DeviceInfo, Byte[]& Result, String& Extension, String& MimeType, String& Encoding, Warning[]& Warnings, String[]& StreamIds)
```

I have no idea of this error or what to do to correct this. But I think that this must be about the class HeaderExecute. If someone can help me I would appreciate it very much

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/christophputz/2010/05/07/accessing-ms-reporting-services-with-java/